# Is there a way to indent each line of every paragraph in an entire document?

Tags: formatting

Is there a way to indent each line of every paragraph in an entire document?  I'm typing the minutes for our meetings and the chairperson wants the paragraphs to look like this.

[image]

I have a template file created and I would like to be able to change this for the entire document not for each individual paragraph if possible.  I attached the tex code I have below if that helps.

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{wallpaper}
\graphicspath{{../}}
\ThisULCornerWallPaper{1}{RVCC_letterhead.pdf}

\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{*2}{*0}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{*0}{*0}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{*0}{*0}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nolistsep}

\begin{document}

\null
\vspace{10mm}
\begin{center}
{\huge \textbf{Council of the Staff Minutes}}
\end{center}

\vspace{5mm}

\begin{description} 
    \item[Chair]{Roberta Harmon}
    \item[Secretary]{Justin Farischon}
    \item[Participants]{17}
    \item[Guest]{N/A}
    \item[Date of Meeting]{February 27, 2018 10:00-11:00}
    \item[Location]{Robeson Room - Library}
\end{description}

\section{Call to Order and Welcome}
    Meeting was called to order at 10:09.

\section{Approval or Correction of January 23, 2018 Minutes}
    Motion was made to approve the minutes as distributed. Motion was seconded.

\section{Chair's Report}
    \subsection{Substantial Completion of the Forum Constitution \& Bylaws}
        The Forum Constitution and Bylaws are in the final draft and will be going for electronic vote soon.  The Ad-Hoc Committee worked for several months on the new Constitution and Bylaws to make them simplified and easier to follow.  

    \subsection{Revised Campus Display Policy}
        The Diversity Council is proposing a policy on how they will hand complaints for campus displays.

\begin{center}
``\textbf{Challenge process:}  Any member of the RVCC community who objects to the content of a campus display must express their concerns in writing and submit these to the Chair of Diversity Council for review by the CDC.  A response to such a complaint will be provided by the Chair of the Diversity Council within 48 hours.  However, no action related to the exhibit may be taken until the CDC has made a decision about the complaint and delivered their response. This policy applies to all members of the RVCC community, including students, employees, and visitors.''
\end{center}
    \subsection{Responding to items of concern brought to the Forum Steering Committee.}
        Forum steering committee is addressing more general concerns, now that the academic committees have moved to a separate Academic Steering Committee.
\begin{itemize}
            \item{Smoking policy - (Will need representation on an Ad-Hoc Committee)}

                The Forum was charged by the President to review and revamp the College no-smoking policy. The Forum Steering Committee created an Ad-Hoc Committee to handle this issue. Rose Arroyo volunteered to represent the Council of Staff on the Ad-Hoc Committee.

                We discussed problems with the old policy.  Including how no one was keeping track of the fines and that the students are not required to have College ID cards.  

                It was mentioned that Security would have to be the ones to enforce the no smoking policy.              
            \item{Wheelchair Access}

                Last Forum it was brought to attention that several areas of the college are not truely accessable to handicapped members of the college.  We discussed that the power doors in many areas of the college are not working.  And that they seem to be constantly broken.
            \item{Parking}
            \item{Campus Safety (in light of the Florida shooting)}
\end{itemize}       

\section{Committee Report - Community Life (Parking - Cindy Coulbourne)}
    The Community Life Committee has been tasked with looking into and proposing recommendations to the President.  Some of the proposed ideas include hang tags or stickers for vehicles, registering vehicles, a shuttle for cars parked in Lot 5 and having transient parking spaces specifically for adjunct faculty that are only here for an hour or two.  It was mentioned that students are parking in staff parking spots, and that there is plenty of parking in Lot 5.

\section{Nominations for the Forum (Vice-Chair (2yr term) \& Secretary (1yr term))}
    It was mentioned that the Forum Steering Committee Vice-Chair \& Secretary positions are open for nominations this year.

\section{Nominations for CoS (Chair, Vice-Chair \& Secretary)}
    It was mentioned that the Council of Staff positions of Chair, Vice-Chair \& Secretary will be open for nomination this year.  Roberta Harmon was renominated for the Position of Chair.  No one was nominated for the position of Vice-Chair.  Justin Farischon was renominated for the Position of Secretary.

\section{Old Business}
    Ronnie Weyl is looking for interest from Council of Staff for $50^{th}$ Anniversary Committees.  Particularly, the 12 themes subgroup and the events of campus subgroup.  Roberta will send an email with the list of tasks for each group.

\section{New Business}
    Friday March $2^{nd}$, in Conference Center Room B \& C, There will be a Forum meeting where the President will go over the college budget.

    Friday April $13^{th}$, in E109, the President will explain the plan for the student dormitory.

\section{Good of the Order}
    N/A

\section{Motion to Adjourn}
    Motion was made to adjourn at 11:04.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Similar question: [horizontal alignment - Indent an entire paragraph / section? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30965/indent-an-entire-paragraph-section)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of indenting every line you can increase the margin and move the titles into the margins.

The indention of the titles is controlled by the second parameter of `\titlespacing`, so you have to set for example

```
\titlespacing*{\section}{-2em}{*2}{*0} // Move the section title 2em to the left.
```

To get the start of the paragraph title aligned with the text, such that only the number is in the margin, you can instead use `\titleformat`. With `\llap` you can let the number be on the left of the normal position without using any space, such that the title text is at the right position:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{wallpaper}

\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\llap{\thesection\hspace{1em}}}{0em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\llap{\thesubsection\hspace{1em}}}{0em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\llap{\thesubsubsection\hspace{1em}}}{0em}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{*2}{*0}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{*0}{*0}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{*0}{*0}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nolistsep}

\begin{document}

\null
\vspace{10mm}
\begin{center}
{\huge \textbf{Council of the Staff Minutes}}
\end{center}

\vspace{5mm}

\begin{description} 
    \item[Chair]{Roberta Harmon}
    \item[Secretary]{Justin Farischon}
    \item[Participants]{17}
    \item[Guest]{N/A}
    \item[Date of Meeting]{February 27, 2018 10:00-11:00}
    \item[Location]{Robeson Room - Library}
\end{description}

\section{Call to Order and Welcome}
    Meeting was called to order at 10:09.

\section{Approval or Correction of January 23, 2018 Minutes}
    Motion was made to approve the minutes as distributed. Motion was seconded.

\section{Chair's Report}
    \subsection{Substantial Completion of the Forum Constitution \& Bylaws}
        The Forum Constitution and Bylaws are in the final draft and will be going for electronic vote soon.  The Ad-Hoc Committee worked for several months on the new Constitution and Bylaws to make them simplified and easier to follow.  

    \subsection{Revised Campus Display Policy}
        The Diversity Council is proposing a policy on how they will hand complaints for campus displays.

\begin{center}
``\textbf{Challenge process:}  Any member of the RVCC community who objects to the content of a campus display must express their concerns in writing and submit these to the Chair of Diversity Council for review by the CDC.  A response to such a complaint will be provided by the Chair of the Diversity Council within 48 hours.  However, no action related to the exhibit may be taken until the CDC has made a decision about the complaint and delivered their response. This policy applies to all members of the RVCC community, including students, employees, and visitors.''
\end{center}
    \subsection{Responding to items of concern brought to the Forum Steering Committee.}
        Forum steering committee is addressing more general concerns, now that the academic committees have moved to a separate Academic Steering Committee.
\begin{itemize}
            \item{Smoking policy - (Will need representation on an Ad-Hoc Committee)}

                The Forum was charged by the President to review and revamp the College no-smoking policy. The Forum Steering Committee created an Ad-Hoc Committee to handle this issue. Rose Arroyo volunteered to represent the Council of Staff on the Ad-Hoc Committee.

                We discussed problems with the old policy.  Including how no one was keeping track of the fines and that the students are not required to have College ID cards.  

                It was mentioned that Security would have to be the ones to enforce the no smoking policy.              
            \item{Wheelchair Access}

                Last Forum it was brought to attention that several areas of the college are not truely accessable to handicapped members of the college.  We discussed that the power doors in many areas of the college are not working.  And that they seem to be constantly broken.
            \item{Parking}
            \item{Campus Safety (in light of the Florida shooting)}
\end{itemize}       

\section{Committee Report - Community Life (Parking - Cindy Coulbourne)}
    The Community Life Committee has been tasked with looking into and proposing recommendations to the President.  Some of the proposed ideas include hang tags or stickers for vehicles, registering vehicles, a shuttle for cars parked in Lot 5 and having transient parking spaces specifically for adjunct faculty that are only here for an hour or two.  It was mentioned that students are parking in staff parking spots, and that there is plenty of parking in Lot 5.

\section{Nominations for the Forum (Vice-Chair (2yr term) \& Secretary (1yr term))}
    It was mentioned that the Forum Steering Committee Vice-Chair \& Secretary positions are open for nominations this year.

\section{Nominations for CoS (Chair, Vice-Chair \& Secretary)}
    It was mentioned that the Council of Staff positions of Chair, Vice-Chair \& Secretary will be open for nomination this year.  Roberta Harmon was renominated for the Position of Chair.  No one was nominated for the position of Vice-Chair.  Justin Farischon was renominated for the Position of Secretary.

\section{Old Business}
    Ronnie Weyl is looking for interest from Council of Staff for $50^{th}$ Anniversary Committees.  Particularly, the 12 themes subgroup and the events of campus subgroup.  Roberta will send an email with the list of tasks for each group.

\section{New Business}
    Friday March $2^{nd}$, in Conference Center Room B \& C, There will be a Forum meeting where the President will go over the college budget.

    Friday April $13^{th}$, in E109, the President will explain the plan for the student dormitory.

\section{Good of the Order}
    N/A

\section{Motion to Adjourn}
    Motion was made to adjourn at 11:04.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need to write any text on the `\section` level (i.e. without indentation), [Marcel's suggestion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/423295/48973) is probably the easiest solution. If you do, here is a suggestion. (I use KOMA-Script (`scrartcl`), which lets you format the subsection headings very easily.)

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newlength\subsectionindentlength
\setlength\subsectionindentlength{5ex}

% 1. fixed number width
\makeatletter
    \RedeclareSectionCommand[indent=\dimexpr -\subsectionindentlength\relax]{subsection}
    \renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
        \ifstr{#1}{subsection}{%
            \hskip #2\rlap{#3}%
            \@hangfrom{\hskip\subsectionindentlength}{#4}%
        }{%
            \@hangfrom{\hskip #2#3}{#4}%
        }%
    }
\makeatother

% 2. fixed number indentation and distance to heading
%\makeatletter
%   \RedeclareSectionCommand[indent=\dimexpr -\subsectionindentlength\relax]{subsection}
%\makeatother

% 3. fixed heading indentation and distance to number
%\makeatletter
%   \renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
%       \ifstr{#1}{subsection}{%
%           \@hangfrom{\llap{#3}}{#4}%
%       }{%
%           \@hangfrom{\hskip #2#3}{#4}%
%       }%
%   }
%\makeatother

\makeatletter
    % create commands to indent and unindent (but not multiple times)
    \def\subsection@@indent{%
        \par\begingroup
        \advance\leftmargin\subsectionindentlength
        \advance\linewidth-\subsectionindentlength
        \advance\@totalleftmargin\subsectionindentlength
        \parshape\@ne\@totalleftmargin\linewidth
        \@setpar{{\@@par}}%
    }
    \def\subsection@@unindent{\par\endgroup}
    \let\subsection@indent\subsection@@indent
    \let\subsection@unindent\relax
    \def\subsectionindent{%
        \subsection@indent%
        \let\subsection@indent\relax%
        \let\subsection@unindent\subsection@@unindent%
    }
    \def\subsectionunindent{%
        \subsection@unindent%
        \let\subsection@indent\subsection@@indent%
        \let\subsection@unindent\relax%
    }
    % modify \section and \subsection as to take care of indentation
    % \par is necessary to make sure the indentation does not take place in the paragraph before the hea
    \preto\section{\par\subsectionunindent}
    \preto\subsection{\subsectionindent}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Indentation}
Text here is not indented.

\subsection{First}
Text here is.

\setcounter{subsection}{12}
\subsection{Thirteenth, really really long subsection title, that does not fit into a single line and has to be broken}
Everything should work fine.

\end{document}
```

The tree blocks at the top (two commented) present three alternatives:

1. We could fix the width of the subsection number so that the heading starts indented the same as the text (as in your example). If you have a lot of subsections, you may need a rather large indentation (as in your example). Just increase the value of `\subsectionindentlength` if you prefer this possibility.
   [image: first possibility]
2. We could fix the distance of the subsection number to the heading (as is usually done). Depending on the indentation, the Heading (especially when it is long) will not start (or continue) at the same indentation as the text. On the other hand, you need not worry about the length of your number.
   [image: second possibility]
3. We could fix both the indentation of the heading and the distance of the number to the heading (much like in Marcel's answer). Here, the subsection numbers will not all start at the same indentation (and may even start in the margin).
   [image: third possibility]

The command that does the actual indentation is essentially taken from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237551/indent-text-without-using-trivlist).

Comment: If you really do not want to use KOMA-Script, I am sure this concept can be applied to the standard classes. (That may be a bit more tedious, though.)